# Scrapy parse date in webpage

Tags: date, scrapy, format

I parsed the date in a webpage:

```
<div class="solliciteren-voor">
<span class="label">Apply no later than : 
</span>
<span>September 30, 2017
</span>
</div>
```

using:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="solliciteren-voor"]//span/text()').extract()[1]
```

However, the result was: "30/09/2017", not expected "September 30, 2017"

How did this happened? Will the scrapy automatically transfer the date into a specific format? How do we control this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy doesn't modify the data it downloads. More probable reason is that in the page source, the value is `30/09/2017` (i.e. what you obtained), but some frontend technology (e.g. JavaScript) formats the date during page rendering.

Comment: Yes, I checked the source code, exactly as what you said. Thanks~